# Google profile picture not rendering

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I can't figure out why my Google profile picture isn't showing after I log in. All of my other information can be displayed (email, name, etc.). This is the `function` for loging in with Google:

```
const signInWithGoogle = () => {
        signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then(result => {
            navigate('/todos');
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        })
    }
```

And this is the whole Nav component where I want to display my name and profile picture for now:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import "../index.css";
import TemporaryDrawer from './Drawer';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {onAuthStateChanged} from 'firebase/auth'
import {auth} from '../firebase-config';

function Nav() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
      onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
          setUser(currentUser);
      });

  }, [])

  return (
    <nav>
      <Link to='/todos' style={{ color: 'white' }}>{user ? user.displayName : "Not Logged In"}</Link>
      <img src={user?.photoURL} alt=""/>
      <TemporaryDrawer />
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Nav
```

Both `user.displayName` and `user.email` work perfectly, but `user.photoURl` doesn't work. Does this have to do with Firebase's storage?

Comment: It should be photoURL not imgURL which one did you use

Comment: Check whether you get the profile image url in the user object by using a console.log after the setUser(currentUser) method.

Comment: @Min Oh sorry. I meant to write that `user.photoURL` doesn't work.

Comment: @shehanpathirathna Yes, I'm getting the profile image and that's why I'm not sure why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was probably very tired and couldn't think, but the solution was quite easy, because I had the fix I needed in my own code. I just used the same method for displaying the users image as for displaying other information.

```
<img src={user ? user.photoURL : ""} alt="profile-pic" />
```

Comment: Please mark your own answer as an Answer if it has solved your issue.

Comment: @LikiCrus how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

By adding referrerPolicy="no-referrer" in the img tag , we can solve the google image not showing problem !!!

`<img src={data.user_image} referrerPolicy="no-referrer" />`